# Avoid REST service to be consumed twice

Tags: spring, rest, httpsession

I have a question about Spring MVC controllers scope and REST services. I have a couple of REST services, which returns a token in the response so I can later recreate the state of the application, but I don't want the users use the same token twice, so I've decided to save an unique identifier inside the token and also in HttpServletRequest, so I can check it when I get the requests (a new identifier is generated in every request).

So, my questions are:

1. is there any other way to be sure that some user will not use the same token more than once (also considered to save that identifier in DB, but I would have lot of queries to insert, delete, verify, etc.).
2. is it ok for the controller that receives the requests to be a singleton, or should it be prototype? (considering that the identifier is taken from session and I don't want to mix it between different sessions).

Comment: REST and HTTP session identifiers don't sound well in the same sentence.

Comment: I believe he meant ajax.

Comment: Hi @dit, actually I consume the REST service through an ajax call, but is still REST and HTTP session

Comment: I think the same as you @CássioMazzochiMolin, that's why I'm asking about any other approach, I don't know how to control it

Comment: @maxivis you can not have both REST and Http-Session, since REST = `Session free`. You have just AJAX-Calls with json.

Comment: yes, that's correct, but is there any way to control the user don't consume the service twice?

Comment: What is your actual intend? Consuming one-time-pad like tokens after their usage or the recreation of a certain user-state on providing a token? It is unclear if a simple state retrieval should consume a token or if a token should be generated/consumed only for updates done to a state of a resource.

Comment: @maxivis Let me know if my answer works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A few words on tokens that are valid only once

It's not possible to achieve it
without keeping the track of the tokens somewhere. This security schema require some trade-offs, *deal with it.*

Give the user a token and keep the track of it on server side, just like a *white list*:

- When a token is issued, add it to the white list.
- When a request comes to the server with a token, check the white list and:

  - If the token is valid, accept the request and remove the token from the white list.
  - If the token is invalid, refuse the request by returning a proper status code such as [`403`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.3).

Also, consider assigning an expiration date to the token and refuse any request that comes to the server with an expired token.

Regarding your performance concerns: Bear in mind that [*premature optimization is the root of all evil*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/80092/122966). You shouldn't optimize until you have a performance problem and you *have proven* that the performance problem comes from the way you store your tokens. You could start storing the tokens in the database and then consider a cache in memory, for example. But always be careful when fixing a problem that you currently don't have.

### Working with JWT

If you go for [JWT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519), there are a few Java libraries to issue and validate JWT tokens such as:

- [jjwt](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt)
- [java-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt)
- [jose4j](https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/wiki/Home)

The [`jti`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.7) claim should be used to store the token identifier on the token. When validating the token, ensure that it's valid by checking the value of the [`jti`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.7) claim against the token identifiers you have on server side.

For the token identifier you could use [UUID](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122). In Java, it's as simple as:

```java
String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

Comment: Hi @CássioMazzochiMolin, thank you for your answer, that's how I've implemented it previously, but as it implies to write the token in DB, then read it, and if it's correct delete it, I automatically assumed that it would lead me to performance problems, but you're right about the premature optimizations, I'll give you +1 for that concept, and I'll keep the question open a few more days, in case another user has another suggestion.

Comment: Turned out that, at least locally, the performance using the DB approach was pretty good, so I've leave this implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Since [HttpSession#getId()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19857-01/819-6518/6n8hd7te2/index.html#abxdg) is unique, you can use it to create an unique token:

```
// pseudo code
String token = httpSession.getId() + "-" + System.currentTimeMillis();
```

You can also create your own counter.

Comment: Thanks @dit for your response, but my problem is not how to generate the token, it's the approach itself, should I use a token (identifier) or is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Here my two techniques to prevent it

1. Disable submit button:
   We can disable submit button right before our function call HTTP request and enable it again after finish gets HTTP response. This technique is effective for the process that takes a long time to finish (more than 5 sec.). The user can not click n’ click again because of impatience to get the result. Additionally, we may show a loading box for a good experience.
2. Issue request token/id:
   This technique actually more complicated and difficult to implement, but thanks to a good framework (such as Spring Boot) to make this easier. Before we are going to the code implementation, let’s talk about the mechanism first;
   When form page is loaded, issue a new requestId
   put issued requestId to HTTP header before calling the backend service
   backend service identify a requestId is already registered or not
   if requestId is already registered then we can mark as a violation request